# Simplifying algebraic fraction, exponents

Tags: exponentiation

Would someone be able to tell me how
$$\bigg( \frac{5}{a^4} \bigg)^{-3}$$
gets simplified to 
$$\frac{a^{12}}{125}?$$

Thank you!

Comment: -3=-1*3 so what does this tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a dirty but quick way as a rule of thumb: 
we have
$$
\bigg( \frac{5}{a^{4}} \bigg)^{-3} = \bigg( \frac{a^{4}}{5} \bigg)^{3} = \frac{a^{12}}{125}
$$

I use "dirty" here because the number $a$ should be $\neq 0$.

Comment: So to reverse powers, you flip the fraction? Does that work in all cases?

Comment: @Spica In fact, for all $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $a,b \neq 0$ we have $$\bigg( \frac{a}{b} \bigg)^{-1} = \frac{b}{a}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You have:

$$
\left(\frac{5}{a^4}\right)^{-3}=\left(\frac{5^{-3}}{a^{-12}}\right)=\left(\frac{a^{12}}{5^3}\right)=\frac{a^{12}}{125}
$$